# Cell formula to use a different sheet with sheet.name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with coding a cell formula to use a different sheet but getting the sheet name using 
sheet.name:

```
Set sht = Activesheet
 Sh_name = sht.Name
 Range("C4").Formula = _
   "=SUMIF(""'"" & Sh_name &""'!$D:$D"",'Trial balance'!B4,""'"" & Sh_name &""'!$G:$G"")"
```

this is what I did but it's not working...

any ideas why?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet
Sh_name = sht.Name
Range("C4").Formula = "=SUMIF('" & Sh_name & "'!$D:$D,'Trial balance'!B4,'" & Sh_name & "'!$G:$G)"
```

Why? Let's have an hard-coded sheet name like 'Sheet1'. Our code would be:

```
Range("C4").Formula = "=SUMIF('Sheet1'!$D:$D,'Trial balance'!B4,'Sheet1'!$G:$G)"
```

And now we are going to use "Sheet1" as hard-coded sheet name but concatenating the fixed structure of the formula with the sheet name.

```
Range("C4").Formula = "=SUMIF('" & "Sheet1" & "'!$D:$D,'Trial balance'!B4,'" & "Sheet1" & "'!$G:$G)"
```

To concatenate strings you have to write a list of strings, separating them by the ampersand '&'. A string could be a text between doulbe-quotes or a variable name.
The final step is to replace the strings "Sheet1" with a variable name, like your Sh_name:

```
Sh_name = "Sheet1"
Range("C4").Formula = "=SUMIF('" & Sh_name & "'!$D:$D,'Trial balance'!B4,'" & Sh_name & "'!$G:$G)"
```

Your expected result:

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet
Sh_name = sht.Name
Range("C4").Formula = "=SUMIF('" & Sh_name & "'!$D:$D,'Trial balance'!B4,'" & Sh_name & "'!$G:$G)"
```

Comment: Nicely explained. (Alas, no idea as to correctness.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("C4").Formula = _
 "=SUMIF('" & Sh_name & "'!$D:$D,'Trial balance'!B4, '" & Sh_name & "'!$G:$G)"
```